# Is it possible to customize the F12 goto definition behavior of Visual Studio Code C/C++ extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code

My C project has some special symbol lookup rules, which is very different from the conventional one. Is it possible to customize the Visual Studio Code or its C/C++ extension's F12 goto definition behavior? Thanks.

Comment: I assume that you are already aware of this, but have you checked this: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_advanced-customization ?

Comment: Thanks. That's helpful. My current `F12` key binds to something like this `editor.action.goToDeclaration`. I guess this is from the `Microsoft C/C++ extension for VS Code`. I think this is the command I need to further customize. But seems the `C/C++ extension` is not open-source.